# Yocto: Nothing provides python-re-native

Tags: yocto

I'm running into an issue including python pyparted as a native dependency in one of my image creation bbclasses.

There is a python scrip that runs to create a partitioned image file, normally I run *sudo apt install python-pyparted* to have pyparted in the environment in ubuntu. But I'm not sure what I did (update??), the ubuntu environment is completely ignored now. I tried figuring out how to make sure the dependencies are correct in my sdimage bbclass.

```
do_image_sdimage[depends] = "parted-native:do_populate_sysroot \
                            dosfstools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
                            mtools-native:do_populate_sysroot \
                            virtual/kernel:do_deploy \
                            splash-images:do_deploy \
                            python3-native:do_populate_sysroot \
                            python3-pyparted-native:do_populate_sysroot \
                            ${@d.getVar('IMAGE_BOOTLOADER', True) and d.getVar('IMAGE_BOOTLOADER', True) + ':do_deploy' or ''}"
```

I get an error showing

```
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'python3-re-native' (but virtual:native:/home/dev/app/OS/sources/meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-extended/python-pyparted/python3-pyparted_3.10.7.bb DEPENDS on or otherwise requires it). Close matches:
  python3-rpm-native
  python3-native
  python3-nose-native
  python3-native RPROVIDES python3-re-native
ERROR: Required build target 'my-image-default' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['my-image-default', 'python3-pyparted-native', 'python3-re-native']
```

based on this it looks like I *should* be able to do this, but the depency chain ignores python3-native's RPROVIDES?

Comment: `python3-pyparted` recipe should depends on `python3 (not `python3-re`) as `python3` provides `python3-re`

Comment: So it seems like I need to bbappend this and override the DEPENDS for python3-pyparted

Comment: Which Yocto version do you use?

Comment: Rocko, 

I added bbappend with 
````
DEPENDS_remove += "python3-re"
DEPENDS += "python3"
````
And that didn't seem to work. It got past the error but still had an issue with the import parted

Comment: Did you look at differences between [master](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-extended/python-pyparted/python-pyparted.inc?h=master) and [rocko](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-extended/python-pyparted/python-pyparted.inc?h=rocko), especially `RDEPENDS_${PN}_class-target` part?